# does to new intuit quickbooks online migration apply to using the QBSDK12 and earlier

Tags: api, sdk, quickbooks-online

In a recent email from Intuit we seen in the migration pages that the QuickBooks online

To:
developers currently using the QuickBooks Online SDK (aka QBO XML SDK (SOAP)) to access QuickBooks Online company data.
and
migrating QuickBooks Online SDK to QuickBooks Online REST API v3 .

on

https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2013/12/19/2014-roadmap-and-migration-dates-for-existing-developers
and
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0058_faq/qbo_xml_sdk_%28soap%29_to_v3_rest_migration

Does this apply to the QBSDK12,11, etc. that support QBO.

Comment: Please post this question to IPP Live Community.  It will likely be closed on SO because it is not a technical question. https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com

Answer (score 0):

If you're using qbXML to communicate with QuickBooks Online, then it applies.

This includes ANY and ALL *QuickBooks SDK* applications that communicate with QuickBooks Online. The entire SDK is qbXML based, so any SDK apps that deal with QuickBooks Online need to be ported to the new REST v3 API.

> Does this apply to the QBSDK12,11, etc. that support QBO.

Yes.